# Do these Laplace equations on semi-infinite strips have unique solution?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> 1. On $\{\pi/2>x>0, y> 0\}$ we have $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}H(x,y) +\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}H(x,y)=0$, with boundary conditions
>
> $$H(0,y)=0\,\, (y\geq 0),$$
> $$H(\pi/2, y)=1\,\, (y\geq 0),$$
> $$H_y(x,0)=0\,\, (\pi/2\geq x\geq 0).$$

$H(x,y)= \pi x/2$ is an obvious solution , but how do I know if there're other solutions?

> 2. Usually when solving this kind of problem, separation of variable is used, but how do I know **all answers can be written in that form**? What if the solution has variables can't be separated. Like this problem: [Laplace's equation for a semi infinite strip](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1940956/laplaces-equation-for-a-semi-infinite-strip)

Uniqueness theorems I found in PDE books all require the domain to be compact, so I'm confused on semi-infinite strip.

Comment: As far as I understand this is a situation where dimensionality comes into play. In the probabilistic analogy, in 2D Brownian motion is recurrent so the behavior at infinity is not required to specify a solution and so the solution is actually unique. In 3D BM is transient, so the value at infinity contributes to the expected value of $u(B_\tau)$ where $\tau$ is the boundary hitting time. Theorems like Lax-Milgram are agnostic about dimension, so they don't know anything about this kind of distinction. A more computational perspective is to conformally map your domain to a compact one.

Comment: (Also just a nitpick, the solution is $x/(\pi/2)$...)